# How to insert value into xml

Tags: php, xml

For example I have file config.xml
in that file I have following xml content

```
<cruisecontrol>
  <project name="Project" buildafterfailed="true">
     <property name="QtDir" value="D:\QtSDK"/>
       .
       .
       .

  </project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

I need to be able to put value from php script
in this line

```
<property name="QtDir" value="New value"/>
```

Is there any way to do it without scanning this file like usual one? I mean how can I do it if I know that it is xml file, and I know that I need to change only this typies of lines.

Thank you on advance.

Comment: are you saying you don't want to use `simplexml_load_file();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try;

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($yourXml);
$property = $xml->addChild('property');
$property->addAttribute("name", "QtDir");
$property->addAttribute("value", "New Value");
echo $xml->asXML();
```